# Setting Up NetBeans Spacing To Be Compatible with vi

Tags: php, vim, netbeans, vi, spacing

So I use NetBeans 8.1 for Windows, and a coworker uses vi/vim on the Ubuntu Command Line.  We share code on the same projects with git.

Apparently, Netbeans and vi treat spacing, tabs, etc and formatting differently.  How can I set Netbeans to treat spaces/tabs the same as vi?  Let's face it vi people are set in their ways and won't be the ones to adapt -- I mean, they are using vi still ;)

FYI, the code we are using is PHP  / Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's "vi", not "VI".

Second, he is probably using Vim and not vi.

Third, both of you should simply use [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/#download).

Comment: Fixed the ALL CAPS.  No, I think he uses vi.  At a linux command line, he simply does "vi myfilename.php" and then he's off editing inside it.

Comment: `vi` is actually an "alias" to `vim` but that's beside the point anyway. Editorconfig will solve your issues.

Comment: Oh I see.  It's the command to launch vim.  Ok, thanks for your recommendation.